# Blue imp file upload - Preview of image is not displaying with admin LTE 3

Tags: jquery, blueimp

I am trying to integrate blueimp file uploader on my already existing admin LTE3. When I select add files, images are being added on the browser, but preview of images are not displaying. When I see inspect element

`<tr class="template-upload fade in">` `in` was adding dynamically and

```
fade:not(.show) {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

this was showing in transitions.scss. Actually this class was in adminlte.css. When I add opacity as 1 instead of '0', Images are displaying, but I was thinking this will lead to some issue with modal dialog boxes etc..
Please guide me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use at least blueimp 10.4.0 and set the option showElementClass='show'
For reference see
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/3537